# I am not able to add CSS to elements when appended using append in JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css, web

I have added all the codes used which is bugging a lot

Below is the code

```
<div id="notCompleted">
            <h3> Not Completed</h3>
            <div class="tasks" id="1">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <label> I have a bike</label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Below is JQuery

```
    var taskNumber = 0;

    function insertTask(d) {

        if ($("#plainText").val() != '') {

            $("#notCompleted").append('<div class="tasks" id="' + taskNumber + '">',
                '<input type="checkbox">',
                '<label>' + d + '</label>',
                '</div>');
            $("#plainText").val('');
            taskNumber++;
            console.log(taskNumber);
            console.log(d);
        }

    }
```

Below is CSS

```
.tasks{
    margin: 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(141, 190, 145);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate your string with `+` to make a complete html snippet otherwise jquery takes each one as a separate statement.

Updated snippet:

```js
var taskNumber = 0;

function insertTask(d) {

  if ($("#plainText").val() != '') {

    $("#notCompleted").append('<div class="tasks" id="' + taskNumber + '">'+
      '<input type="checkbox">'+
      '<label>' + d + '</label>'+
      '</div>');
    $("#plainText").val('');
    taskNumber++;
    console.log(taskNumber);
    console.log(d);
  }

}
insertTask("abc");
insertTask("def");
```

```css
.tasks {
  margin: 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(141, 190, 145);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="notCompleted">
  <h3> Not Completed</h3>
  <div class="tasks" id="1">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <label> I have a bike</label>
  </div>
</div>
```